# C++ MySQL database connection

Tags: c++, mysql

I not a DB expert, so am looking for advice for a web-based system I'm thinking of setting up.

The general set up of the system I have is that it will have a web-based interface (possibly in PHP) for logging in etc, and some C++ code running on the server doing some processing. Both the PHP and the C++ code will need read/write access to the MySQL DB.

So, (1) What is the best way to access/update a MySQL database with C++?

(2) Are there any issues/things I should be aware of with a DB that has concurrent access from both PHP and C++. I'm kinda assuming that the DB looks after all that...

Thanks,

Lehane

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DB should take care of concurrent access. You can consider using [MySQL++](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/) as a library to access mysql from C++ code. I only know of its existence, with no usage experience, so I cannot tell you about usability.